# Анализ командной строки

Tags: c#

На вход приложения из командной строки подаются парамаетры вида

```
-***:*** -***:***
```

где `***` - это произвольная буквенная последовательность. Каким образом наиболее просто нужно разбирать командную строку в хэш-таблицу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String s = "-A:red -B:dotted";
var parsed = from item in s.Split()
    let z = item.Split(new char[] { ':' })
    where z.Length >= 2 && z[0][0].Equals('-')    
    select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(z[0], z[1]);

Dictionary<string, string> console_params = new Dictionary<string,string>();
foreach (var item in parsed)
{
    console_params.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
}

foreach (var item in console_params)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} = {1}",item.Key.ToString(), item.Value, item.ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Для регулярной структуры

```
-***:*** -***:***
```

удобно использовать регулярные выражения.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var options = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (string arg in args)
    {
        Match match = Regex.Match(arg, @"\-(?<argname>\w+):(?<argvalue>.+\b)");

        if (match.Success)
        {
            options[match.Groups["argname"].Value] = match.Groups["argvalue"].Value;
        }
    }
}
```